# Django ajax url not reading

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have an ajax file which calls the url from the `urls.py` which gets the json data from the `views.py` but when I run the server it just shows `Not Found:/dept-json/`

I did manage to get it to work using the django snippet `{% url 'accounts:dept-json'%}`

However I do not want this since I need to get and pass the variable from the `dept-json data` to another ajax url which is:

```js
url:`/prog-data/${selectedDept}/`
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55051326/passing-a-parameter-through-ajax-url-with-django#:%7E:text=Votes-,3,POST%20you%20can%20send%20the%20ID%20in%20the%20posted%20data.,-Share) that you can't pass variables in ajax like  `{% url 'accounts:prog-json' department%}`

how do I manage to do this?

> here is my code:

**main.js**

```js
//First ajax
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/dept-json/",
//    url: "{% url 'accounts:dept-json'%}",
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
//Second ajax
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `/prog-data/${selectedDept}/`,
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

**urls.py**

```py
    path('dept-json/', get_json_dept_data, name='dept-json'),
    path('prog-json/<str:department>/', get_json_prog_data, name='prog-json'),
```

**views.py**

```py
def get_json_dept_data(request):
    qs_val = list(Department.objects.values())
    return JsonResponse({'data':qs_val})

def get_json_prog_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    selected_department = kwargs.get('department')
    obj_prog = list(Program.objects.filter(department__name=selected_department).values())
    return JsonResponse({'data':obj_prog})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the data in your ajax request like so:

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "{% url 'accounts:prog-json'%}",
    data: {
          'department': selectedDept
        },
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(error){
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

And then on your view you can access that argument from the request:

```py
def get_json_prog_data(request):
    selected_department = request.GET.get('department')
    obj_prog = list(Program.objects.filter(department__name=selected_department).values())
    return JsonResponse({'data':obj_prog})
```

I dont believe you need the parameter in your url, so you should be able to just remove that as we are sending the data in the ajax request.

```py
path('prog-json/', get_json_prog_data, name='prog-json'),
```

Comment: I have updated the url to use the Django dispatcher which you said worked.